# Maximum Area : applied derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, area

We got 2 functions given by $y=x^2$ and $x+y=2$. Find a point $(h,k)$, $h \in (-2;1)$ , at the first function in the way that the rectangle formed has the Maximum Area .
[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Excelent help! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the point $(h,h^2)$ on the parabola, the vertex of the rectangle on the line $x+y=2$ is $(2-h^2, h^2)$, which leads to the area of the rectangle

$$A=h^2(2-h^2-h)$$

Set $A'(h)=h(4-4h^2-3h)=0$ to get $h = 0, \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{73}}8$. It is then straightforward to verify that the maximum area occurs at the point $(\frac{-3-\sqrt{73}}8, \frac{51+3\sqrt{73}}{32})$.